# Use Enum as Parameter in Windsor Configuration File

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

how would I preset a Windsor configuration file parameter with an Enum specified entry such as "EntryType" below?

I currently have this:

```
<component
      id="test.service" service=".." type=".." lifestyle="transient">
      <parameters>
        <entryType>EntryType.Test</entryType>
      </parameters>
    </component>
```

Where `..` obviously represents the full namespace and assembly.

But receiving this error:

```
Could not convert from 'EntryType.Test' to 
   Business.Common.Services.Core.TestService+EntryType.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Written like this, it worked for me:

```
<component
  id="test.service" service=".." type=".." lifestyle="transient">
  <parameters>
    <entryType>Test</entryType><!-- NOT EntryType.Test -->
  </parameters>
</component>
```

Comment: Shamefully easy... Thanks. ;)