# castle windsor xml config file - how to specify enum flags

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

Can you tell me how to configure OR-ed enum flags in castle windsor component xml file? Something like

```
<Parameter>Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag3</Parameter>
```

I know I can bitwise-or the integer enum values but then I lose the descriptive enum names.
Thanks
rg

Comment: I voted to close this as a dupe (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629353/use-enum-as-parameter-in-windsor-configuration-file), but then realized it's slightly different because you want to OR the enums.  Sorry about that.  Not sure if this is possible. I'd have to look at the XML parsing code. Any reason it needs to be in XML and can't be done in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard CLR method of representing enum flags as string is using a comma, so make it

```
<Parameter>Flag1, Flag2, Flag3</Parameter>
```